# How do you format a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to know how to format a dictionary so it looks better when it's printed. This is what I get:

```
{'park': 'Animal Kingdom', 'section': 'DinoLand U.S.A.', 'Attraction': 'The Boneyard', 'Height': 'Any Height', 'Categories': 'Play Areas'}
```

I want it to look like this:

```
park: Animal Kingdom
section: DinoLand U.S.A.
Attraction: The Boneyard
Height: Any Height
Categories: Play Areas
```

Comment: pprint is a library for 'pretty printing': `import pprint; pprint.pprint(mydict)`

Answer (score 1):

[`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)(“pretty-print”) is exatly what you are looking for:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint 
>>> d = {'park': 'Animal Kingdom', 'section': 'DinoLand U.S.A.', 'Attraction': 'The Boneyard', 'Height': 'Any Height', 'Categories': 'Play Areas'}
>>> pprint(d)
{'Attraction': 'The Boneyard',
 'Categories': 'Play Areas',
 'Height': 'Any Height',
 'park': 'Animal Kingdom',
 'section': 'DinoLand U.S.A.'}
```

Alternatively, you may use a simple loop:

```
>>> for key, val in d.items() : print("%s : %s" %( key, val))
...
park : Animal Kingdom
section : DinoLand U.S.A.
Attraction : The Boneyard
Height : Any Height
Categories : Play Areas
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
    print '{} : {}'.format(key, my_dict[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through all the elements and print them one at a time:

```
mydict = {'park': 'Animal Kingdom', 'section': 'DinoLand U.S.A.', 'Attraction': 'The Boneyard', 'Height': 'Any Height', 'Categories': 'Play Areas'}

for key in mydict:
    print(key,":",mydict[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all of the items in the dictionary and format the key and value in a string. The for loop below should work for what you are trying to do.

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Hope this helps!